# SQL summary of missing numbers in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands, number-sequence

I would like to find gaps in a sequence and summarize the findings in the following way:

number sequence: `2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15`
missing numbers: `0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11`
min number: 0 (always)
max number: max number of the sequence (15 in this example)

The summary should look like:

```
From | To | # of missing  
00   | 01 | 2  
05   | 07 | 3  
10   | 11 | 2
```

I am using SQL server and in reality, the sequence will contain many more numbers (close to a million). I have found many scripts that find and list the missing numbers in the sequence, but I can't figure out how to summarize it in the desired way.

If it helps, the field is called `BELNR` and the table is called `BSEG`.

EDIT:
with the help from the Gaps and Islands material, I have been able to find a solution (may not be the most optimal one, but I think it works):

```
with C as
(
select belnr, row_number() over(order by belnr) as rownum
from bseg
)
select cast(Cur.belnr as bigint) + 1 as [From], cast(nxt.belnr as bigint) - 1 as [To], (cast(nxt.belnr as bigint) - 1) - (cast(Cur.belnr as bigint) + 1) + 1  as [# of Missing]
from C as Cur
join C as Nxt
    on Nxt.rownum = cast(Cur.rownum as int) +1
Where cast(nxt.belnr as bigint) - cast(Cur.belnr as bigint) > 1
```

Comment: your output looks incorrect. from and To have values from missing numbers

Comment: You say "_I have found many scripts that find and list the missing numbers in the sequence_" ...please include that information and what it produces with the above dataset, this will show that you have a partial solution and you want to format the output into a summary. Otherwise, you're relying on users to create 2 solutions for you, when you already have the first part.

Comment: @ughai: I want to show the Gaps (missing values)  
Tanner: I have posted the code I used above

Comment: my point exactly. you are missing values 5,6 and 7 however you have a row `05   | 07 | 3`. how did you decide to get 5 and 7 and exclude out 6 from your output

Comment: it was meant as a range - from 5 to 7, which includes the numbers 5, 6, 7 (thus the number of missing is 3). In real world examples I am missing ranges with 10k or more missing numbers, so it would make no sense to list them all. Sorry for the missunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Islands and Gaps problem. Read more here:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

> The word ‘Gaps’ in the title refers to gaps in sequences of values.
>   Islands are unbroken sequences delimited by gaps. The ‘Gaps and
>   Islands’ problem is that of using SQL to rapidly detect the unbroken
>   sequences, and the extent of the gaps between them in a column.